# Includes with only certain attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to do something like:

```
Book.includes(authors: {only: :first_name})
```

I only want that attribute, not the whole Author model.

Comment: you can use `select`

Comment: you can select on the included model?  Can you show me how that works? My select keeps picking up from Book

Comment: `Book.includes(:authors).select('authors.first_name')`

Comment: [like hear](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't. If you don't want to load all the data you can load the books and then run a separate query on authors to bring their names alone:

```
books = Book.where(something_here)
author_ids = books.map(&:author_id)
author_names = Author.where(id: author_ids).pluck(:id, :first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `select` to get the `:first_name` property of each author.

```
authors_first_names = Author.select(:first_name)
```

See [selecting specific fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) in the Rails Guide for Active Record Query Interface.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
Book.joins(:authors).select("books.*, authors.name as author_name")
```

Every instance in the resulting relation will repond to `author_name` without executing an additional SQL statement.